# Request.IsAuthenticated function in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there an equivalent to `Request.IsAuthenticated` in ASP.NET 5 hidden somewhere or are we expected to loop through the user's identities and determine this ourselves?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you just need to know if the User object is authenticated, this property should do the trick:

```cs
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

If you need to prevent an action from being called by an unauthenticated user, the following attribute class works great.

```cs
public class BasicAuthAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

I use this in my base controller class as follows.

```cs
[BasicAuth]
public abstract class BaseAuthorizedController : Controller
```

Comment: there's an [Authorize] attribute already in the framework and you can add the attribute as a global without using a base controller like: opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build())); There's also an [AllowAnonymous] attribute so you can have that in your login page for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can also access the `IsAuthenticated` property from within your service layer by injecting an `IHttpContextAccessor` into it, like this:

```cs
public class MyService : IMyService {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccesor;

    public MyService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void MyMethod() {

         var isAuthenticated = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

         if (isAuthenticated) {
             // Authenticated, do something!
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is great ! worked in Net core 5 , Thank you so much.